# fs.rename immediately after fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, filesystems, rename

Is it safe to `fs.rename` a file immediately after a call to `fs.writeFile` (but before the `callback`)?

*The [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) didn't answer this, it only says:*

```
Note that it is unsafe to use fs.write multiple times
on the same file without waiting for the callback.
```

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that it isn't safe. Is there any reason you need this?

Comment: I think the question here is _"what happens to a file descriptor when the file is renamed"_? If the file is still valid, then everything works. But it's not actually clear what "in" the file descriptor as it is not described as a class on that page.